# How to get all the data from form at once and save in database in Django?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I am calling the form in template as:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

Now, when the user submits the form I want to get the data at once. Something like this:

```
info = form.POST
```

and save in video table like this:

```
video = info.save()
```

Is this possible in Django? I can get each field one by one and save it in database. But I want to do this quick way.

Comment: Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine you've a Django model form class (you cannot save in DB directly a simple form since there is no corresponding schema, but you can with a model form)

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
  field1 = forms.IntegerField(...)
  ...
```

You rendered it in a template with `{{ form.as_p }}`

Then in the reception view, do the following:

```
def myview(request):
  if request.method == "POST":
    form = MyForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save() # here you save the form all at once
    else:
      ... # here return the "form" to the template, and render it with form.as_p: it will display the validation errors
  else:
    ... # here treat the get request. If not get: return an Http 404 response
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I am using modelform. I have a little problem. I have to add one field manually : user_id field. It's a foreign key to User table. How can I do that?

Comment: Simply add the field to the `ModelForm`, like its's done with `field1` in the answer.

Comment: I never tried, but you could use django formset __https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets__ to get inline forms. Then in the view, try to create many those same forms from __request.POST__. But I've no solution in mind..